# Why is my resolution wrong?

Tags: resolution

I'm not sure if this is the right place or not, so I apologize if it isn't. Anyway, I am a total noob to Ubuntu and Linux as a whole, for starters. I just installed Ubuntu 14.10 on my Desktop PC. My 24" monitor has a native resolution of 1920x1080, but I can't seem to get past 1024x768. My processor is an Intel Core i3-4130, and I manually installed the Haswell graphics using the Intel Graphics Installer. My drivers and everything are working, but the resolution just won't go higher. I should also note that my previous operating system, Windows, ran the native resolution just fine.

Comment: May be try adding a modeline to your xorg.conf file to accommodate for that screen resolution.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Ok, I feel very nooby saying this: I fixed it. It worked when I switched from VGA to DVI for some reason :D